How to calculate $\int(yy'' + (y')^2)\,dx$?
Context: I have the following second-order differential equation:
$$yy'' + (y')^2 = x$$
I noticed that
$$yy'' + (y')^2 = (yy')'_x \,\,\,\, (1)$$
So I integrate both sides with respect of $x$:
$$\int(yy'' + (y')^2)\,dx = \int{x\,dx}$$
I already know the answer for the left integral: $\int(yy'' + (y')^2)\,dx = yy' + C_1$.
But what if I didn't notice $(1)$? How would I solve the integral? I'm struggling for some reason..

For the differential equation, make $y=z^n$ and look for which value of $n$ the equation simplifies a lot.

Even if you couldn't have noticed the $vu' + uv'$, you could still do through integration
Integrating through by-parts:
\begin{align*}
\int yy'' + (y')^2 \, dx &= \int yy'' \, dx + \int (y')^2 \, dx \\
&= \int y \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \, dx + \int (y')^2 \, dx \\
&= y y' - \int (y')^2 \, dx + \int (y')^2 \, dx \quad \text{(Integrating by parts)} \\
&= y y'
\end{align*}
Hope it helps!

Exactly what I was about to comment ^^

Thank you! That was quite confusing for we since I've done integrals like $\int{yy',dx}$ before. It was a new experience for me
